# Не могу разобраться с работой типов float И double в C

Tags: c

Коллеги, добрый день! начал изучать C. Столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Есть простейший код

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double a = 32.00000007;
    printf("%Lf", a);
    return 0;   
}
```

По моему мнению после запуска программы в консоль должно выводиться исходное число 32.00000007

Однако, почему-то оно зануляется и вывод вот такой: 32.000000
В случае с short Это было понятно и объяснимо, но не пойму, чем вызвано подобное поведение с типом double

Comment: То, что шесть знаков вывелось - ни на какие мысли не навело? `printf("%12.9lf", a);`

Comment: Стоит отметить, что исходное число вы теряете уже при превращении литерала в `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы использовали %Lf, который предназначен для вывода значений типа long double. А ваша переменная double, не long double.

Попробуйте использовать %f или %lf. Можно даже точность вывода после запятой указать, например, %.<число знаков>f.

Ваш примерчик:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double a = 32.00000007;
    printf("%.8f", a); 
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! ваша идея с указанием точности помогла!

Comment: @ArthurMedvedev, между прочим в комментарии вам как раз про точность подсказали

Comment: @avp Не понял смысла вашего комментария. Я поблагодарил человека за его идею с указанием точности

Answer (score 0):

У вас ввод 32+7*10^-8 а вывело у вас лишь 6 *цифр* после натурального. Для того, чтобы вывело 8 *цифр* (до позиции семёрки), нужно написать не `printf("%Lf", a);` а `printf("%.8f", a);`.

Comment: Тогда уж не "чисел", а "цифр"...